# Custom Swing layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm creating a game and to set up the frame the way I want it, I need to some how create a costume layout.  I have tried creating multiple panels with different layouts such as Flow and Border and adding panels on the main panel but I still don't get the desired outcome.  What I desire is shown in the attached picture.  Please tell me if any code segments would help.
Questions: 
1. Is it possible to get such layout? (I want it to be fixed.)[image]

2. Under the "button" there is the JLabel you see in the picture.  I want its text to start from left, go down the column, and start on the middle, and then to the right column.  Is that possible?

Comment: It's not exactly a code segment but if you use an IDE like Eclipse, you can get WindowBuilder, and you can easily design GUIs.

Comment: I'm. It using eclipse, I'm using jgrasp which is basically just pure coding.  Should I transfer to eclipse

Comment: This layout is simple, if I am not wrong. Simply take a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` as the root. Now add a `JPanel` to the `PAGE_START` location, with `BoxLayout`, and another `JPanel` to the `CENTER` with `GridLayout`. This will do :-)

Comment: Ooo that is smart.  Now will the texts remain on the label and go down the row and the over to a column if I use q grid layout?

Comment: For 2. you don't use a `JLabel`, you use a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`.

Comment: But then I would have to Crete a label for each text I want to add right?  By the way, the number of texts depends on how well. User plays the game.

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy Use a `JList` with a `VERTICAL_WRAP` (via the [setLayoutOrientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setLayoutOrientation(int))) method, which is demonstrated in [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) ... for the "labels" at the bottom

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you.  After looking at the documentation, however, I don't see how I can add texts to JList. Is that possible

Comment: Amazingly you can just about anything to a `JList`, and with a good `ListCellRender`, make it look just about anyway you want, but yes, as the tutorials demonstrate, text is the most simplest ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight variation, as to what I wrote in comments, since `BoxLayout` is somethingy, that I never use, since I am not good in it :-)

Though what I did to overcome, this shortcoming of mine, is to take 2 `JPanel`s, one each for `JTextField` and `JButton` and the rest is the same, as shown in this example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutExample {    

    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private static final int TOTAL_LABELS = 18;

    private JTextField tField;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel[] labels;

    private void displayGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Layout Example" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel contentPane = getPanel ();
        contentPane.setLayout ( new BorderLayout ( GAP, GAP ) );

        JPanel headerPanel = getPanel ();
        headerPanel.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 0, 1, GAP, GAP ) );
        JPanel textFieldPanel = getPanel ();
        tField = new JTextField ( 10 );
        textFieldPanel.add ( tField );
        JPanel buttonPanel = getPanel ();
        button = new JButton ( "Button" );
        buttonPanel.add ( button );     
        headerPanel.add ( textFieldPanel );
        headerPanel.add ( buttonPanel );
        contentPane.add (headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START );

        JPanel centerPanel = getPanel ();
        centerPanel.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 0, 3, GAP, GAP ) );
        labels = new JLabel [ TOTAL_LABELS ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i ) {
            labels [ i ] = new JLabel ( String.valueOf ( i ), JLabel.CENTER );
            centerPanel.add ( labels [ i ] );
        }
        contentPane.add ( centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );


        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    private JPanel getPanel () {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setOpaque ( true );
        panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP ) );

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                new LayoutExample ().displayGUI ();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater ( runnable );
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FMcV9GS.png]